# How to package Flutter libraries

Tags: flutter, libraries, packaging

Flutter noob question: What is the right way to distribute Flutter libraries (i.e. custom libraries we've created in Flutter)? Does it provide a way to create a compiled library for a particular target OS (for e.g. compiled for android, iOS etc.)? We're creating a flutter SDK to distribute to our clients and would like to provide some kind of library that they can import and use but not see the implementation details of.

Answer (score -1):

here is the documentation

[developing-packages](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)